# Need help in connections and code of a gsm module to trigger a call with a raspberry pi 3

Tags: pi-3, gsm

Hello so i need the code and connections for a gsm module triggering a call i have searched like ton of sites and youtube and found no help if you could help me and explain the code and connections that would be really helpful

Comment: You question is not very clear. Do you mean something like this? (1) Connect Rpi to a GSM module using a UART/serial cable, (2) Use python to wake up the GSM module and ask it to text SMS messages to another mobile phone? If you already found the code, perhaps you can give us the link to (a) Your GSM module, (b) The tutorial and code?

Comment: Nothing to do with the Pi.

Comment: And if your module is SIM800/900/7600, you can search this forum for other users sharing their setup/troubleshooting experience of using AT commands to do their jobs.

Comment: I have been using SIM7600 Rpi HAT and found it newbie friendly, using USB serial ports and AT commands. But now there is the new Rpi4B HAT 3G/4G/5G Cellular Connectivity with Snapdragon X55/SimCOM SIM8200EA-M2 M2 - CNX (US$399 Kit):
https://www.cnx-software.com/2020/10/16/raspberry-pi-gets-5g-cellular-connectivity-with-snapdragon-x55-powered-hat/. Cheers.

Comment: If you like that many user read your question, then please write proper sentences with some punctuation marks.

Comment: you are asking for connections and code for an unknown module ... your question is like asking how to connect a cardboad box to the RPi

Comment: Yes my bad.i want to know if i can use a if stantment and trigger a call with a gsm modulse at first i wanna know if its possible and then which gsm is good or can i use the one from my friend which idk the name of but if i can anyway msg one of u personally i could elobrate that

Comment: Tlfong i need exactly what u said can i contact u by any means instagram or something